# About PHP connection object

Tags: php

Could somebody explain to me why the following is wrong :

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM images';
$hostname ='localhost';
$username= 'root';
$password= '';
$db= 'myDB';

$numRows=new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db)->query($sql)-> num_rows;
```

The error throws is : syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR .....

and is it possible to correct it in one statement like above ? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to try such a hideous thing? Database operations can and do fail - chaining like this assumes success and will simply blow up on you at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain *after* your instantiate mysqli.

```
$m = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);
$numrows = $m->query($sql)->num_rows;
```

Comment: Yes that works bsdnoobz, but logically it should also work the way I put it above. The object is already created and is executing the function. Trying to figure out the logic behind objects and chaining .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Place brackets around `new mysqli(....)`.

ie. Place the following:

```
$numRows=(new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db))->query($sql)-> num_rows;
```

Instead of:

```
$numRows=new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db)->query($sql)-> num_rows;
```

But as **@MarcB** said, This is a very hideous thing to do. Later, debugging would be difficult.

Comment: Hi Ahmedtabrez, still putting brackets as you indicated didn't solve the error.